# Why is binded prop not reset in parent when child component is rerendered via {#key}?

Tags: svelte

Given this scenario [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a534bf821bd448639b3f6e6152e8e236?version=3.47.0) when opening the page the binded value which is undefined in the parent is set via the binding to the value from inside the component.
But when the value is changed and the component is rerendered via a `{#key}` block, the value in the parent isn't reset again, but stays the changed value which is then also set in the rerendered component.

Why doesn't the binding work in this case? Is this due to the order in which the components are mounted the first time?

###### App.svelte

```
<script>
    import Comp from './Comp.svelte'

    let value

    let rerender=true
</script>

{#key rerender}
<Comp bind:value />
{/key}

<p>
    {value}
<!--    isn't reset by rerendering the component -->
</p>

<button on:click={() => rerender = !rerender}>
    2. rerender Comp
</button>
```

###### Comp.svelte

```
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'
    
    export let value = 'startValue'
    
    onMount(() => {
        console.log('Comp mounted, value >', value)
    })
</script>

<button on:click={() => value = 'changedValue'}>
    1. change value
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind:value` is a two-way binding.

In your code (and your REPL), the first time you render the component, `value` is `undefined`, hence the `value` prop *inside the child* is set to the default value, which in turn changes `value` in the parent because of the two-way binding.

The second time the component is rendered, however, `value` is **not** `undefined` in the parent component since it has been set to an actual value, which is either `startValue` if you never clicked on the change value button, or `changedValue` if you did. So the `value` prop received by the child component is no longer `undefined`, and hence the default value is not used.

If you actually reset `value` to `undefined` whenever you re-render your component, you will see `startValue` again whenever you click on the re-render button: [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4fe9a506872c4dd7ac649822d58e638b?version=3.47.0)

Answer (score 1):

The value in the component is only a default, see [the docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-attributes-and-props):

> You can specify a default initial value for a prop. It will be used if the component's consumer doesn't specify the prop on the component (or if its initial value is undefined) when instantiating the component.